# Inheriting BasePage class works for some, not all pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've inherited a VB.Net 2.0 site and am building the project in Visual Studio 2010. All the aspx.vb code-behind files inherit BasePage that exists in the App_Code folder. What has me stumped is that some of the classes are aware of BasePage and other are not but I cannot find  a pattern. Being new to VB.Net, I'm not sure where to start looking.

The inheritance statement looks like this for all files:

```
Partial Class SomePage_Default
    Inherits BasePage
```

The code works when deployed, this problem is just in my development environment, restricting me from running it locally.

What could I be missing that denies some access to App_Code\BasePage.vb

Comment: What do you mean by "works for some"? Does it throw an error?

Comment: The inheritance declaration has an error and any statement that requires the inherited class. The class doesn't show up in VS's autocomplete list but does for others. The files seem to be set up the same, with no differing imports.

Comment: Is your BasePage has namespace? or perhaps the other page are in different namespace?

Comment: There are no namespace declarations in any of the files. I should add that the code works when deployed, but VisualStudio 2010 won't run it.